# Socket.io Client side, is there a way to keep receiving data when lost focus on the broswer?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

is there a way to keep receiving data when lost focus on the broswer on Socket.io Client side?

I'm making a multiplayer game test with html5 and nodejs as server, everything works fine, but i have the case that if the client (the game), lost the focus, for example move to another windows or tab, it stops receiving information, then when a i focus again a receive all the data on the queue

Comment: Which browser are you seeing this in and are you using timers (`setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`) in your game to send data or to process incoming data?

Comment: i have setInterval(1000/60) , but Socket.io works with Events , so dont constantly check the incoming data from the gameloop, i don't know if i can request to socket.io a certain message outside their specifict events

Comment: I don't have the issue you speak of in Chrome.  I have a socket.io page that continues to receive data even when the tab is in the background (not the active page).  Different browsers may do background tabs differently which is why I asked which browser you see this in.  I asked about timers because pretty much all browsers slow or delay timers in background pages (to save battery).

Comment: I tested with chrome , but it happen with any browser,

Comment: I can't duplicate your issue in Chrome with my page that uses socket.io so it doesn't appear to be any sort of specific limitation with socket.io.  A background tab seems to get socket.io messages just fine as they arrive.  There must be something else your app is doing that is triggering this behavior.  But, without seeing an app that folks can look and play with, I'm not sure what else we can do.